# Import the side effectful library in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I want to import a UI library in Angular 15, but in dev, and presumable prod as well, the import is ignored.

```
import '@spectrum-web-components/bundle/elements.js;
```

is the file that imports all the web-components provided by the library, and it looks like this:

```
import '@spectrum-web-components/accordion/sp-accordion.js';
import '@spectrum-web-components/accordion/sp-accordion-item.js';
import '@spectrum-web-components/action-bar/sp-action-bar.js';
...
```

If I import all these components individually, then they are registered, but not when using the bundle file. If I use dynamic import() it seems to be working, but that's not what I want to use.

How to make this single file import work?

Answer (score 0):

**Answering my own question.**

Solved it with `import * as myModule` syntax, and then `console.log(myModule)` so it is used and not ignored.